# Layer in keras like regressionlayer in matlab?

Tags: matlab, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to write the code in keras from already written Matlab Model in example here:https://in.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/examples/denoise-speech-using-deep-learning-networks.html

They have defined a layer in the end called regressionLayer. I want to know what to use corresponding to this in keras or pytorch.

I have simply added the sigmoid activation rather than this regressionLayer in keras. But I doubt if this is correct because I dont seem to get the desired output and this seems to be one of the reason.

```
model.add(Conv2D(1, (129,1), strides =(1,100),padding='same',
                 input_shape=(129,8,18),activation='sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab the regression layer just computes a mean squared loss, which is the way Caffe works (losses as layers), but not the way Keras works, so the equivalent line would not be a layer, just setting the loss:

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=...)
```

Note that we do not include accuracy metrics if you are doing regression, as it is a classification only metric.

Comment: @DEEPANSHUSINGH18210027 Remember to upvote/accept if the answer solves your problem.